# How do I use the `node_modules` folder that NPM generates for a simple website?

Tags: npm, node-modules

In the past I've manually downloaded vendor JS such as jQuery or RequireJS and saved them in my repo under `/vendor/js`. I'd like to use NPM to manage all of that for me and clean up my repo a little.

I've built a `packages.json` file and used `npm install`, but I'm not sure what the best way to use the `node_modules` folder that it generates is.

Should I link directly to the script files in `node_modules`?

`<script src="/node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>`

Or should I use some other tool (gulp?) to move the contents of `node_modules` somewhere else after it's installed?

This isn't a Node app, just a simple front-end website that would work on any server, e.g. a LAMP stack.

Comment: Generally you would not link directly to the node_modules folder for your library references. You would build your app first using either grunt, gulp, or `npm build`. Then your newly-built files would go into a public folder. Check out https://github.com/angular/angular-cli for example. You can install the cli quickly, and then quickly create and build a sample app. I hope this helps...

Comment: Ok, I see. So the build command would copy the entire contents of `node_modules` into some sort of `/buld` directory in some folder similar to how I normally structure things, e.g. `/build/vendor/js` and then I can deploy the entire `build` directory.

Comment: the build will not copy the entire contents of `node_modules` to your build folder, no. Node_Modules it not meant for deployment - just for development. If you `npm install  -g @angular/cli`, then create a sample app, you can then `ng build` to see the resulting `dist` folder which is created. Also see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki for some basic steps.